# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\{(2+ \sqrt{3})^n\}$, where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$

Tags: number-theory

Be $x$ a number, denote $[x]$ the greater integer number that is smaller than $x$, and denote $\{x\} = x - [x]$.
For example:

$$x = 1,71 \qquad [x] = 1 \qquad \{x\} = 0,71$$

> What is the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\{(2+ \sqrt{3})^n\}$ ?

I have been seeking for any pattern, but i didn't not found anything. My guess would be open it as a series, but i think this would be too much cumbersome. I would appreciate any help to start with maybe a better way.